# .bashrc loading aliases from different file

Tags: bash, alias, bashrc

I have a .bashrc file, which I want to setup so it reads aliases from an .aliases file and sets them up.

Currently I have:

```
# User specific aliases and functions
while read alias_line
do
        echo `alias ${alias_line}`
done < .aliases
```

But upon login I get:

> -bash: alias: -fu: not found
>   -bash: alias: $USER": not found
>
> -bash: alias: -lart": not found

The .aliases file is like this:

> psu="ps -fu $USER" 
>   ll="ls -lart"
>   pico='nano'

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you use `alias ${alias_line}`, the variable is broken up at spaces, *ignoring* quoting rules.

There are two ways you could fix it:

- Remove all quoting from the alias file:

  ```
  ll=ls -lart
  psu=ps -fu $USER
  ```

  and put the variable itself in quotes:

  ```
  alias "$alias_line"
  ```

  This works because in bash, `ll="ls -lart"` and `"ll=ls -lart"` are exactly equivalent.
- Alternatively (this is a better and more common way), have a file with `alias` commands, and use the `.` builtin (aka `source`) to import it.

  ```
  alias pico='nano'
  alias psu='ps x'
  alias ll='ls -lart'
  ```

  then in your `~/.bashrc`:

  ```
  . ~/.aliases
  ```

**The second method is better**, since it does not limit you to aliases, but also allows defining *functions*, which are much more powerful.

Comment: That's right. It was a completely wrong approach. I did it myself using these commands:

while read line; do echo "alias $line" >> .aliases_full; done < .aliases
I then just did

mv .aliases_full .aliases
. ./.aliases #in .bashrc
Thanks anyway :)